# Qt C++ qextserialport

Tags: qt

I'm using qextserialport library to write a C++ code that allow me to send a message if I received a specific message request.

Now I don't know how can I write a code that allow me to compare between the different received requests.

for example the request shall be "@10201" through the serial, if I received such message the led shall be ON and a new message will be sent.

Comment: If you receive strings, just compare two [`QString`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html) objects?

Comment: basically what I did is: QString r("#01"); if(QString::fromLatin1(port->readAll())==r){ ui->led->turnOn();} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Remember that the comparison operator compares the *whole* strings. So if you read more than the header `"#01"` then the comparison will fail. You should first make sure that you got the whole message, then compare only a sub-string of the received message.